# Two launcher activities creating two APKs

Tags: android

I recently added a splash-screen to my app and made it as launcher activity to display it when the app started, the manifest looks like,

```
<activity android:name=".LaucherActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

And I have the MainActivity which is already a launcher activity in the manifest shown below,

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    s

        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So, this is actually creating two APKs, one for the splash and the other main activity. But I wanted the SplashActivity and MainActivity in the same APK running one after the other. How can I achieve that? I found many related questions but none of them are working for me.

Comment: it's making two launcher actually , remove intent-filter from mainactivity, and use startActivity intent for start mainactivity from splash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<intent-filter>` only once in manifest. like this

```
<activity android:name=".LaucherActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentTheme">

</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class LaucherActivity extends Activity {
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(LaucherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from you MainActivity.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>
```

Now call your MainActivity from your Splash Activity